# Sin tener que cerrar la aplicación que se reinicie una clase

Tags: c#

Tengo un programa en C# con un try catch cuando me da un error me dice lo que es , pero lo que quiero es sin tener que cerrar la aplicación que se reinicie la clase. Reiniciar (class ProcessMonitorSample)
En este programa uso bucle.

¿Esto es posible sin tener que usar bucle ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace Processes_Remote_computer
{
    class ProcessMonitorSample
    {    
        public static void Main()
        {
            int data2 = 1;

            while (data2 == 1) {

                Console.Clear();

                try

            {                    

                //conexion puerto serial
                SerialPort spPuertoSerie = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

                    spPuertoSerie.Open();
                int data1 = 1;

                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    while (data1 == 1)
                {

                    // conexion de la PC al HMI
                    Process[] targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("VUServer");
                    int proLen = targetProcess.Length;

                    // lee el puesto serial 
                    string data4 = spPuertoSerie.ReadExisting();
                    string data3 = "1";

                    //area de comparar data de lectura Serial

                    if (data4 == data3)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("bit de envio de data " + data4);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);   
                        Console.Clear();
                    }

                    //area de  verifica que la PC esta conectada al HMI
                    if (proLen != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The process status is: Running");
                        spPuertoSerie.Write("1");
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        Console.Clear();                                
                        }

                    if (proLen == 0)
                    {                           

                        Console.WriteLine("The process does NOT exist or has exited...");
                        spPuertoSerie.Write(" ");
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        Console.Clear();    

                        }
                }

                }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);                       
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            //area de salida si hay un error
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(" !Espere! Reinciando el Progrma ");

                Thread.Sleep(5000);

            }                
        }           
    }    
}​
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo involucrado y lo que estas haciendo y que queres exactamente que pase? al parecer segun la pregunta que hiciste, la respuesta es si.. pero no se entiende nada...

Comment: Hola, podrias compartir lo que estas haciendo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: y cual seria la clase que queres reiniciar?

Comment: me falto esta parte del programa disculpe
namespace Processes_Remote_computer
{
    class ProcessMonitorSample
    {

Comment: eso esta (lo que pasa es que el codigo esta mal identado, presiona CTRL+K con todo el codigo seleccionado para arreglarlo). Vuelvo a la misma pregunta, que clase queres reiniciar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a instanciar la clase de nuevo en un finally. Por lo que veo en tu codigo donde tienes puesto el comentario de "area de salida si hay un error" no se ejecuta solo si hay un error, se ejecuta siempre porque esta fuera del catch.

Yo lo pondría así

```
class ProcessMonitorSample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int data2 = 1;

            while (data2 == 1)
            {

                Console.Clear();

                try

                {

                    //conexion puerto serial
                    SerialPort spPuertoSerie = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

                    spPuertoSerie.Open();
                    int data1 = 1;

                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    while (data1 == 1)
                    {

                        // conexion de la PC al HMI
                        Process[] targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("VUServer");
                        int proLen = targetProcess.Length;

                        // lee el puesto serial 
                        string data4 = spPuertoSerie.ReadExisting();
                        string data3 = "1";

                        //area de comparar data de lectura Serial

                        if (data4 == data3)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("bit de envio de data " + data4);
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            Console.Clear();
                        }

                        //area de  verifica que la PC esta conectada al HMI
                        if (proLen != 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The process status is: Running");
                            spPuertoSerie.Write("1");
                            Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            Console.Clear();
                        }

                        if (proLen == 0)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("The process does NOT exist or has exited...");
                            spPuertoSerie.Write(" ");
                            Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            Console.Clear();

                        }
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    //area de salida si hay un error
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine(" !Espere! Reinciando el Progrma ");

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                finally
                {
                    clase_a_reiniciar = new clase_a_reiniciar();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```